# Handling error in RoboSpice

Tags: android, error-handling, robospice

I'm new in Robospice and I'm having a problem in handling error request. Is there a way that I can access the Response body from an error request in onRequestFailure method? If not, how you guys do it?

```
private class RequestListener implements RequestListener<Object> {
    @Override
    public void onRequestFailure(SpiceException e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestSuccess(Object response) {

    }
}
```

There's a suggestion that I should do the error checking inside the Spice Request. Any suggestion guys?

```
@Override
public SubscriptionsContainer loadDataFromNetwork() {
    ResponseEntity<SubscriptionsContainer> response = null;
    try {  
        response = getRestTemplate().exchange(/*your request data*/);
    } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
       String responsebody =  e.getResponseBodyAsString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you throw any exception from `loadDataFromNetwork()`, it will be wrapped as `SpiceException` and passed to `onRequestFailure()` as its argument.

Therefore, you should check your `ResponseEntity<T>` for the conditions you expect and throw an exception in case those are not fulfilled.
If, on another hand, your `RestTemplate.exchange` call throws an exception, you could also handle it (as in your example) or let it be thrown (so it will be reported with `onRequestFailure()` on the main thread).